# Swift: Getting target of UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

In my ViewController.swift, I have an array that contains custom UIViews. Every time one is created, I add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to it like this:

```
var panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "detectPan:")
newCard.gestureRecognizers = [panRecognizer]
```

This links to my `detectPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)` function, which handles movement. However, since I have multiple objects linked to the function, I'm not sure how I determine from which one the input is coming.

Is there anything like (the nonexistent) `recognizer.target` that I could use? Should I just handle the panning from within each of the custom UIViews instead?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The `recognizer` parameter is the recognizer that's being activated. If you have more than one you can just compare it to find out which one you are receiving events from.

Comment: Would something like this work? `if(recognizer == customViewArray[0].gestureRecognizers[0]) {
            println("First view has been panned")
        }`

Comment: It wanted my to do `customViewArray[0].gestureRecognizers[0] as! NSObject` but it didn't work with or without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should declare your `panRecognizer` with `let`.

```
let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "detectPan:")
```

Second of all, you should not set the `gestureRecognizers` property of any `UIView`. This is bad practice because UIKit may have already added its own gesture recognizers to that view behind the scenes. If you subsequently remove those recognizers by assigning `[panRecognizer]` to that property, you may get unexpected behavior. To add your pan gesture recognizer, do this:

```
newCard.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
```

Then, in your `detectPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)` method you can detect which `UIView` was panned with the following code:

```
func detectPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.view {
    case self.customViewArray[0]:
        // do something
    case self.customViewArray[1]:
        // do something else
    case ... :
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer! You provided even more than I need.